# Different validation on a field depending on user selection

Tags: validation, symfony

For example lets say I have the following validator:

```
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Person:
    properties:
        ID:
            - NotBlank: ~
```

However the kind of validation for `ID` depends on the property `IDType` that is selected by a user. Which some IDS can be blank and some cannot. Not only that but other types of ID needs other types of validation. Is this possible to do? Or should I have one property for each `ID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `Callback` validation constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) is very suitable in this case. It lets you define complex validation logic and add errors to any form field you see fit.